# Ansible Builtin Shell: how can I get a table output instead of "\t" delimiters?

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, delimiter

While checking a port range on my nodes with following playbook extract,

```yaml
  - name: bash commands
    ansible.builtin.shell: |
      grep -E '\b(500[0-9]|50[1-9][0-9]|5[1-4][0-9]{2}|5500)' \
      /etc/services | sort -k 2
    args:
      chdir: /root
      executable: /bin/bash
    async: 2000
    poll: 3
    register: output
  - debug: msg="{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
  - debug: msg="{{ output.stderr_lines }}"
```

I am getting below sample output, where everything is concatenated with `\t` delimiters:

```
ok: [sea_r] => {
    "msg": [
        "enbd-cstatd\t5051/tcp\t\t\t# ENBD client statd",
        "enbd-sstatd\t5052/tcp\t\t\t# ENBD server statd",
        "sip\t\t5060/tcp\t\t\t# Session Initiation Protocol",
        "sip\t\t5060/udp",
        "sip-tls\t\t5061/tcp",
        "sip-tls\t\t5061/udp",
        "pcrd\t\t5151/tcp\t\t\t# PCR-1000 Daemon",
        "xmpp-client\t5222/tcp\tjabber-client\t# Jabber Client Connection",
        "xmpp-server\t5269/tcp\tjabber-server\t# Jabber Server Connection",
        "cfengine\t5308/tcp",
        "mdns\t\t5353/udp\t\t\t# Multicast DNS",
        "noclog\t\t5354/tcp\t\t\t# noclogd with TCP (nocol)",
        "noclog\t\t5354/udp\t\t\t# noclogd with UDP (nocol)",
        "hostmon\t\t5355/tcp\t\t\t# hostmon uses TCP (nocol)",
        "hostmon\t\t5355/udp\t\t\t# hostmon uses UDP (nocol)",
        "postgresql\t5432/tcp\tpostgres\t# PostgreSQL Database"
    ]
}
```

But running the same thing with below bash script,

```sh
for r in "${IPS[@]}"; do
  ssh -tt root@"$r" "
   grep -E --color=always '\b(500[0-9]|50[1-9][0-9]|5[1-4][0-9]{2}|5500)' \
   /etc/services | sort -k 2
   echo -e "continue to next node"; read
"
done
```

it outputs the following nice table:

[image: bash cmd output]

**Is it possible to get such a table output with the playbook instead of those `\t` delimiters?**

Comment: The result you are looking at with the literal `\t` escapes is how Python stores strings; they are unrelated to the actual output, just like the `[`...`,`...`]` demarcation around the list of values. If you somehow print those strings, you should see actual tabs.

Comment: As an aside, nothing in your command line uses any Bash features. Running it in a specific directory also does not seem to provide any benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow Ansible to display values like new lines (`\n`) and tabs (`\t`), you can use the `debug` [callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html).

This can be done, either modifying the *ansible.cfg*, if you want to apply it on your whole Ansible installation, e.g.

```
[defaults]
stdout_callback = debug
```

Or, invoking `ansible-playbook` this way:

```sh
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug ansible-playbook play.yaml
```

---

For example; given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "some\tfields\tin\ttable\nfoo\tbar\tbaz\tqux"
```

When run with the `debug` callback, this yields:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [node1] => {}

MSG:

some    fields  in      table
foo     bar     baz     qux
```

---

In your specific case, what you can, then, do, is:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ output.stdout_lines | join('\n') }}"
```

Which would yield, with the usage of the `debug` callback:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [node1] => {}

MSG:

enbd-cstatd     5051/tcp                        # ENBD client statd
enbd-sstatd     5052/tcp                        # ENBD server statd
sip             5060/tcp                        # Session Initiation Protocol
sip             5060/udp
sip-tls         5061/tcp
sip-tls         5061/udp
pcrd            5151/tcp                        # PCR-1000 Daemon
xmpp-client     5222/tcp        jabber-client   # Jabber Client Connection
xmpp-server     5269/tcp        jabber-server   # Jabber Server Connection
cfengine        5308/tcp
mdns            5353/udp                        # Multicast DNS
noclog          5354/tcp                        # noclogd with TCP (nocol)
noclog          5354/udp                        # noclogd with UDP (nocol)
hostmon         5355/tcp                        # hostmon uses TCP (nocol)
hostmon         5355/udp                        # hostmon uses UDP (nocol)
postgresql      5432/tcp        postgres        # PostgreSQL Database
```